# How do I access objects in HTTP Post response using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

I am using the following code to make an API request to a third party system:

```
var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(URL_ENDPOINT);
req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
req.retries = 2;
req.continueOnError = true;
req.contentType = "application/json";
req.setHeader('grant_type', 'Basic ' + ENCODED_PASS);
req.method = "POST";
req.postData = Stringify(payload);

var resp = req.send();
var res = results.content;
Write(res + "<br>");
var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(res));

try {
    if (json.status == 200) {
        Write("SUCCESS!<br>");
    } else {
        Write("Errors found<br>");
        Write("Error code: " + json.status + "<br>");

    }

} catch (e) {
    Write("fatal error");
}
```

When running this, I get a fatal error with the following response from my Write(res) line:

```
    { "results": [ { "errors": [ { "message": "Key (phone)=(41792232493) already exists." } ], "status": 409, "index": 0 }, { "errors": [ { "message": "Key (phone)=(41792232492) already exists." } ], "status": 409, "index": 2 } ] }
fatal error
```

Comment: I could be reading it wrong, but this looks like the SSJS API call went through fine, the third party endpoint is the one throwing back the error - so debugging of the issue would need to be done there.

Comment: Hey sorry should of been more clear, I’m not expecting a 290 response. When I refer to json.status the exception is fired instead of going into my != 200 condition

Comment: It appears that `status` is not available as an overall return as you have it with `json.status`. status is instead on a per object basis inside the results array on each individual object. So would have to be returned via `json.results[0].status` to get status on first call and so on. Perhaps this is what is causing the error?

Comment: I believe null value in comparison can cause typeerrors which may be why the try is failing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424673/javascript-if-statement-with-null-condition-error

Comment: You're right about the status, this is actually within the list of errors. I've wrongly assumed this is the StatusCode returned from the HTTP Response, using `results.responseCode` I was able to get the return I needed. Could you turn you're second comment in to the answer please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `status` is not available as an overall return as you have it with `json.status`. status is instead on a per object basis inside the results array on each individual object.

So would have to be returned via `json.results[0].status` to get status on first call and so on. Perhaps this is what is causing the error?